# Page focus scrolls back to AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Have an autocomplete textView in layout which is in a ScrollView.

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextValidator(mAutoCompleteTextView) {
        @Override
        public void validate(TextView textView, String text) {
            if(text == null){
                mAutoCompleteTextView.setError(text);
        }
});
```

This shows a red error icon with a dropdown error message in case text is not valid. While error is visible and page is scrolled, the centre of page returns back to this view instead of scrolling up/down.

How to avoid this while error is still visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..
This will allow you to scroll smoothly, if *setEnabled()* doesnt work you can also user *clearFocus()* and *requestFocus()*

```
   scrollLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            mAutoCompleteTextView.setEnabled(false);
            if (mAutoCompleteTextView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)
                    && mAutoCompleteTextView.getHeight() == rect.height()
                    && mAutoCompleteTextView.getWidth() == rect.width() && mAutoCompleteTextView.isShown()) {
                mAutoCompleteTextView.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mAutoCompleteTextView.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the root Layout use this :

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

And then in onCreate():

```
rootLayout.requestFocus();
```

Hope this helps.